# Replaced cmos battery and each time plug in socket. The time will back to 2010

Tags: battery, cmos

I replaced the cmos battery and reset the date. (remark: save and exit bios)

If I unplugged the socket and plug in again.

The bios date will back to 2010 and have to reset time again.

How do I make the time in bios always correct?

Comment: Hypothesis: the new battery is dead or not installed right.

Comment: I'm with Kamil on this. If you make changes to the bios other than time, do those stay saved ?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski It is new battery.

Comment: @Silbee Once the power supply cable is unplugged and plugged in, the bios time will back to 2010. Otherwise it will stay saved.